# How to determine where a function is complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

I know the definition of complex differentiability and also am aware that $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ iff it is real differentiable at $z_0$ and that the partial derivatives satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann Equation.

In general, what are the steps required to show that $f$ is (not) complex differentiable at a point $z\in\mathbb C$?

EDIT: Made a typo on $f(z)$.
I was also given an example of a $f(z)=exp(-z^{-4})$ to show that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations at $0$ but is still not complex differentiable at $0$.

Does it mean that whenever we want to show whether $f$ is not differentiable at $z\in\mathbb C$, the Cauchy-Riemann Equation doesn't give us any information on it and we just have to work with the definition of complex differentiability and find sequences that tend to different limits?

Comment: I'm trying to do this for $f=|z|^2$ I know there's another question already posed for this particular $f$, hence I didn't want to put it up in case it was marked as duplicate. What I'm trying to ask is, is using the C-R equations first to narrow the possibility of where $f$ is complex differentiable any use?

Comment: Of course, the function could even fail to be real-differentiable. In that case, CR are indeed useless.

Comment: For $f(z)=|z|^2=z\cdot\overline{z}$, I would recommend using the more compact form of CR: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}=0$. In this case, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}=z$. So you see where it fails to satisfy CR.

Comment: Another nice way is to use that $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ iff there exists $a\in\mathbb C$ with $f(z_0+h)=f(z_0)+ah+o(h)$ (of course, $a=f'(z_0)$).

Comment: $f(z)=\exp(-z^{-4})$ is not even defined at $z=0$, so of course it does not satisfy CR in the first place. I assume that you considered the (non-continuous) extension obtained from *additionally defining* the value $f(0)=0$.

Comment: For this new $f(z)$, try the points $z_n=\frac{1}{e^{1\pi/4}n}$. Can the function be continuously extended at $0$? Not even speaking of differentiability.

Comment: Thanks julien and Hagen, I've managed to show that it's the new $f$ is not continuous.

Basically, what I gather so far is that I shouldn't jump straight into verifying the C-R equations. I should first check that real-differentiability is first satisfied..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two comments suffice for the specific function:

> $f(z)=\exp(−z^4)$ is not even defined at $z=0$, so of course it does not satisfy CR in the first place. I assume that you considered the (non-continuous) extension obtained from additionally defining the value $f(0)=0$.

– Hagen von Eitzen May 1 at 13:19

> For this new $f(z)$, try the points $z_n=1/(e^{i\pi/4}n)$. Can the function be continuously extended at $0$? Not even speaking of differentiability.

– julien May 1 at 13:24

---

As for the general question:

> Does it mean that whenever we want to show whether $f$ is not differentiable at $z\in \mathbb C$, the Cauchy-Riemann Equation doesn't give us any information on it and we just have to work with the definition of complex differentiability and find sequences that tend to different limits?

That depends on what the function is. If you are given $f(x+iy)=2x+iy$, you'll naturally point to the failure of the  Cauchy-Riemann equations. Working with difference quotients $(f(z)-f(z))/(z-a)$, while possible, would be unnecessarily awkward.

When you inspect a function, you should be able to tell if it looks okay in the real sense, or if there are some quirks. If it looks real differentiable, then the CR equations are the thing to consider. Otherwise you try to disprove real differentiability in some way.